# Redirect without using httpmodule

Tags: 2013, development, redirect, web-config

While something is updating on site pages, I need catch the requests to them and redirect to page notifying about updates. How I can realize redirecting in easier way than adding a httpmodule?  As far as I heard, it can be made in config, but I have never doing something like that, is it suitable case or maybe there is another simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

[IIS HTTP Redirect](http://blogbaris.blogspot.sg/2013/09/ways-to-redirect-http-requests-in.html) is a simple and recommended way to redirect URL in SharePoint.

A [suggestion](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-redirects-revisited-301-302/) for your reference.